# How do I connect the search bar with the uiwebview in Xcode 6 using Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I'm kinda new to coding with Swift and I need help: how do I connect the search bar to my web view so that when I type a search it appears in Google?

My code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController      {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very basic example.  Type this into the textField:  http://www.apple.com

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

        @IBAction func Go(sender: AnyObject) {
            var text = textField.text
            var url = NSURL(string: text)
            var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
            self.webView!.loadRequest(req)    
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.textField.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

[image]

Updated example showing a UISearchBar

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        var text = searchBar.text
        var url = NSURL(string: text)  //type "http://www.apple.com"
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way i can connect the UISearchBar to this code

Comment: Will this also work if i search something with out the url with it. For example, Search Apple instead of http://www.apple.com. Does it automatically google search for apple. If not How do i add that.

Comment: You are going to have to add some text operations to construct aproper URL - be it a direct http website request or a google search request like this: "http://" + "www.google.com" +"/search?q=apple" You can just enter "apple" and then if  your algorithm detects it is not a proper url, then it will have to construct one before handing off to the NSURLRequest.  The google url should be one long string, but the interpreter for this site keeps converting it to a shortened url.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that now